# Bug for installing a specific Linux kernel on qemu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, qemu

I use qemu-nvm because I want to simulate a machine with a open-channel SSD.
I tried the command "qemu-system-x86_64 -hda openChanSSDtest1.img -cdrom ./ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso -m 10G -boot d" and it worked.

However, when I tried "qemu-system-x86_64 -hda openChanSSDtest2.img -cdrom ./ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso -m 10G -boot d -append root=/dev/sda -initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.12.0-rc6 -kernel /home/baoning/Downloads/linux-4.12-rc6/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage", the virtual qemu machine showed the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQivz.png)

I also tried ls /dev/sda and there exists this device.

Searched a lot but found no clue.

Comment: The error message is "Gave up waiting for root device"